# Using templates as a grunt file list

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to use a template for copying some files with Grunt. Currently, I have:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Metadata.
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    libSrc: ['foo/**'],

    // Task configuration.
    copy: {
        libs: {
                src: ["<%= libSrc %=>"],
                dest: 'src/'
        }

    }
  });

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-dojo');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bless');


  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']); 

};
```

My directory structure is:

```
.
./.Gruntfile.js.swp
./src
./src/foo
./src/foo/oops.js
./node_modules
./package.json
./foo
./foo/oops.js
./Gruntfile.js
```

When I run Grunt, I get:

```
grunt copy
Running "copy:libs" (copy) task


Done, without errors.
```

i.e. nothing is copied.

I've tried replacing the template with the *actual* array and things work correctly. The thing is, I'll be modifying the value of `libSrc` with other tasks in a later iteration of this Gruntfile, so I *do* need to be using the template.

The basic grunt docs indicate that this is a supported approach, in particular the sample at http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates.

So, am I missing something here? Why is the template not being expanded to `['foo/**']`? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo!

The line:

```
 src: ["<%= libSrc %=>"],
```

Should have read

```
 src: ["<%= libSrc %>"],
```